# populate flot graph from database

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following jQuery code (I've removed the parts that don't apply to this question):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

  var formData = "f=27/07/2015&t=01/08/2015";

  jQuery.ajax
  ({ 
     url: 'http://www.yourhealthfoodstore.co.uk/test.php',
     type: 'post',
     data : formData,
     success: function(result)
       {

         console.log(result);

         // Graph Data ##############################################
         var graphData = [{
           // Shop                          
           data: result,
           color: '#71c73e'
          }, {
           // Net
           data: [ [1, 900, '27/07'], [2, 1100, '28/07'], [3, 1550, '29/07'], [4, 1600, '30/07'], [5, 1800, '31/07'], [6, 1400, '01/08'], [7, 1300, '02/08'] ],
           color: '#77b7c5',
           points: { radius: 4, fillColor: '#77b7c5' }
          }
         ];

       }

  });

});
```

The console.log(result) is:

```
[[1,"1227.14","27.07"],[2,"1530.40","28.07"],[3,"1235.46","29.07"],[4,"1192.65","30.07"],[5,"1599.85","31.07"],[6,"1350.35","01.08"]]
```

The graph will not plot the result variable:

```
data: result,
```

However will plot the contents of the result variable when pasted directly:

```
data: [[1,"1227.14","27.07"],[2,"1530.40","28.07"],[3,"1235.46","29.07"],[4,"1192.65","30.07"],[5,"1599.85","31.07"],[6,"1350.35","01.08"]],
```

Is there a reason for this?  It doesn't product any errors that I can see, just won't plot.

Comment: Tried `console.log(result instanceof Array)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `dataType:"json"` option to plot your graph like,

```
jQuery.ajax({ 
   url: 'http://www.yourhealthfoodstore.co.uk/test.php',
   type: 'post',
   data : formData,
   dataType:'json',// use this
   success: function(result) {
      ....
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you.  Will accept answer when I'm allowed